# Why doesn't my jQuery AJAX error function work here? It completely messes up the page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

http://christianselig.com/contact.html

On this contact page, when I click submit it will not submit the page as it should. The AJAX should remove the form and put an error or success message. But it won't. If I comment out `error:` section it works perfectly.

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "mail.php",  
                data: dataString,  
                success: function(data) { 
                    $(".contact-form").hide();
                    $(".alt-contact").hide();

                    // Depending on what the PHP script returned, display a message of success or error
                    if (data == 1) {
                        $(".contact-form").html("<div class='success-message'><div class='success-image'></div><div class='success-title'>Success! The message has been sent!</div><div class='success-body'>I'll get back to you right away.</div></div>");
                    }
                    else {
                        $(".contact-form").html("<div class='error-message'><div class='error-image'></div><div class='error-title'>Whoops! An error occurred.</div><div class='error-body'>I'll get back to you ASAP.</div></div>");
                    }

                    $(".contact-form").fadeIn(500);
                }
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $(".contact-form").hide();
                    $(".alt-contact").hide();

                    // Inserts divs making up the success message for the form submission
                    $(".contact-form").html("<div class='error-message'><div class='error-image'></div><div class='error-title'>Success! The message has been sent!</div><div class='error-body'>I'll get back to you right away.</div></div>");

                    $(".contact-form").fadeIn(500);
                }
            });
```

Comment: missing a comma after the `success: function(data) { ... }*,* error:`

Comment: You're missing a comma after your success function. Hit F12 in your browser to use the dev tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're forgetting a comma when specifying the error:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "mail.php",  
    data: dataString,  
    success: function(data) { 
        // code
    }, <----- Right there!
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // code
    }
});
```

Comment: don't cut/paste a huge blob of text and then change only a single character. At least highlight where in the wall of text you made your change.

Comment: better, but still not enough highlighting, e.g. `}, <---comma missing here`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma "," missing before error. Comma is a separator between variables, objects, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Missing comma while separating attributes

```
     $(".contact-form").fadeIn(500);
 } ,  <--------      Missing a comma here
 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
```